# Mathematica: Asynchronous incremental generation of dynamical graphics

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the simplest way to asynchronously apply consecutive improvements to a `Graphics` object in a dynamic setting (and abort the evaluation of the unneeded results if input changes while they are being computed)?

As a simple example, consider this:

```
speed[r_] := Graphics@{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, r]}
qualityA[r_] := (Pause[1]; Graphics@{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, r]})
qualityB[r_] := (Pause[1]; Graphics@{Black, Circle[{0, 0}, r]})
Manipulate[Show[
  ControlActive[speed[r], {qualityA[r], qualityB[r]}],
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
  ], {{r, .5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I evaluate `qualityA` and `qualityB` consecutively, and append their output to the display when it is ready?

Bonus points for `Abort`'ing the evaluation of unneeded results, and for allowing a part of the result to be calculated multiple times, so that after releasing the control I would see e.g. `{qualityA[r]}` then  `{qualityA[r],qualityB[r]}`, and finally `{qualityA2[r],qualityB[r]}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My colleague Lou, an expert on Dynamic, suggested this neat answer:

```
Manipulate[
 ControlActive[
  Graphics[{LightRed, Circle[{0, 0}, r]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  DynamicModule[{exprs = {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, r]}, rr = r},
   Graphics[Dynamic[exprs], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
   Initialization :> (Pause[1];
     AppendTo[exprs, {Red, Disk[{0, 0}, rr]}]; Pause[1];
     AppendTo[exprs, {Black, Circle[{0, 0}, rr]}]),
   SynchronousInitialization -> False]], {{r, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

How it works:

When not ControlActive, the result of the dynamic expression is a `DynamicModule`. The code for refining the graphics is contained in the `Initialization` option of this DynamicModule. The `SynchronousInitialization -> False` makes this initialization run asynchronously.

Renaming `rr = r` in the DynamicModule serves two purposes. First, it makes the result always depend on the Manipulate variable `r`. Second, you can check `rr != r` to decide whether the user has moved the slider during initialization, and abort early, saving computation time:

```
Manipulate[
 ControlActive[
  Graphics[{LightRed, Circle[{0, 0}, r]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  DynamicModule[{exprs = {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, r]}, rr = r},
   Graphics[Dynamic[exprs], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
   Initialization :> (If[rr =!= r, Abort[]]; Pause[1];
     AppendTo[exprs, {Red, Disk[{0, 0}, rr]}]; If[rr =!= r, Abort[]];
     Pause[1]; AppendTo[exprs, {Black, Circle[{0, 0}, rr]}]),
   SynchronousInitialization -> False]], {{r, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This one I cannot break! I really expected your first one to work -- but as mentioned it dies on 'monkey testing'. This one I can fiddle with as much as I want, and just keeps behaving as intended. Thank you very much for pursuing this!

Answer (score 2):

Really good question.

I may be overlooking a simpler way. There often is one when it comes to Dynamic... But here is my suggestion:

```
DynamicModule[{quality = 0, exprs = {}},
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   ControlActive[
    exprs = {}; quality = 0; Graphics@{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, r]},
    Switch[quality,
     0, Pause[1]; quality = 1; 
     AppendTo[exprs, Graphics@{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, r]}],
     1, Pause[1]; quality = 2; 
     AppendTo[exprs, Graphics@{Black, Circle[{0, 0}, r]}],
     _, r];
    exprs
    ],
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  {{r, .5}, 0, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

First we define some variables controlling increasingly high quality graphics: `quality` (ranging to 0 to the maximum quality, 2 in this case), and `exprs` (a list of expressions to Show, just as in your example).

Now note what happens in the two cases of ControlActive:

When ControlActive, the result is the same as yours, except we take the opportunity to reset `quality` and `exprs` relating to the "high quality" graphics.

When not ControlActive, the Dynamic expression evaluates to

```
code; exprs
```

This expression has the following key properties.

1. It returns the list `exprs` every time.
2. Each time `code` is evaluated, it improves the graphics by appending something to `exprs`.
3. Each time `code` is evaluated, at least one of the variables lexically contained in `code; exprs` (such as `quality`) is changed. This means Dynamic will go ahead and evaluate our dynamic expression again, and again, and again, until ...
4. Eventually `code` evaluates without any of the variables lexically contained in `code; exprs` changing. This means Dynamic will stop re-evaluating.
5. The final evaluation lexically contains `r`. (Via the otherwise useless default case in the Switch, `_, r`.) This is important to make the slider still trigger updates.

Give it a try and let me know if that works for you.

Edit: What $Version of Mathematica are you using? I see some version dependence in the behavior of my code above.

Edit 2: I asked an expert on Dynamic and he found a better way, which I will describe in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! This looks pretty much like the idea I was trying to get. Unfortunately it doesn't work too well for me (v8.0, 64bit OS-X): First move-release round is fine, but then the slider stops following, and next everything just stops... And as usual with Dynamics, I have no clue what is going wrong :)